# How can I get join to work with conditions

Tags: sql

I have a table TimeIntervals with a relationship to Breaks with in turn has a relationship to DeletedBreaks.

What i'm trying to do is to receive al rows (Breaks) that has timeIntervals id and no deleted break for a given date.

That is if a break has no deleted breaks, no row in DeletedBreaks table for a break id Or if there is a row with that breaks id but not the given date, than that break should be returned.

Following is not working but you might understand what i'm trying to do:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM Breaks B
JOIN TimeIntervals T
    ON B.TimeIntervalId = T.Id
JOIN DeletedBreaks DB
    ON (
            (
                DB.BreakId = B.Id
                AND DB.DeletedDate <> '2014-10-13'
                )
            OR DB.BreakId IS NULL
            )
        AND (T.Id = 2)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a `LEFT JOIN` to your `DeletedBreaks` table instead of an `inner join` since you don't want to drop `Break` records just becasue the `DeletedBreaks` ID is null.

To test for NULL `DeletedBreaks` or `DeletedBreaks` for a particular day, do so in the `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT B.*
FROM Breaks B
JOIN TimeIntervals T
    ON B.TimeIntervalId = T.Id
LEFT JOIN DeletedBreaks DB ON               
    DB.BreakId = B.Id 
WHERE
    (DB.DeletedDate <> '2014-10-13'
    OR DB.BreakId IS NULL)
    AND T.Id = 2
```